# Installing VirtualBox Guest Additions

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

As a Linux newbie, I'm struggling to install VBox Linux Guest Additions v5.1.12-112440 and could do with some guidance.

Host OS: Windows 7 64-Bit SP1
Guest OS: White Box Enterprise Linux 3.0 Respin 2 (based on RHEL 3, kernel 2.4.21-27.EL)
VirtualBox: v5.1.10 r112026 (Qt5.6.2)

I've got the guest additions downloaded but when I try to install them I get an error in the log file:

> vboxadd.sh: failed: Please check that you have gcc, make the header files for your Linux kernel and possibly perl installed..

GCC v3.2 and MAKE v3.79.1 are definitely installed, as is PERL v5.8.6, so I'm guessing the next problem to solve is "header files for my Linux kernel"...what are these and how do I get them please?

Comment: The package containing your kernel headers (basically, the source code for a kernel) will be in a package called `kernel-devel` or `kernel-headers`. You can install this with your package manager (a quick Google shows me it's `yum` or `up2date`)

Comment: Thank you stuts. I tried "yum install kernel-devel" and got "Gathering header information file(s) from server(s). Server: White Box Enterprise Linux 3.0 - i386 - Base"...then nothing. No prompt or anything. Would you expect the process to take a long time? It doesn't look like it's doing anything.

Comment: It just came back with "retrygrab() failed for: ftp://ftp.opensourcemirrors.org/linux/whitebox/3.0/os/i386/headers/headers.info Executing failover method"

Comment: I'm unsure, I've used CentOS/RHEL but not White Box. Did you use yum to install the other packages (GCC, Make, Perl) or was that done another way?
Sometimes yum hangs while it gathers repository information.

Comment: I didn't specifically install GCC or MAKE, but used MAKE to install PERL (if that makes sense?).

Comment: Couple more "retrygrab() failed" messages with other URLs now...

Comment: Failover: out of servers to try :-(

Comment: Is networking configured on the VM? Can it reach the internet?

Comment: rhel 3 and 4 are EOL and 5 will follow soon so perhaps the repos are not there anymore. you could do a manual search for  the rpm on http://rpm.pbone.net or sites like that and manual install through rpm -ihv package.rpm

Comment: @stuts: No, it can't access the internet, but none of the URLs it tried seem to exist.

Comment: @geegee: I think you might be right. Nothing found on rpm.pbone.net either.

Comment: Please see this answer. CentOS is based on Red Hat. https://superuser.com/questions/1195928/how-do-i-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-for-centos-7/1195929#1195929